# How to define PG connection to a distant server for grass gis v.in.ogr?

Tags: postgresql, connection, grass-7.2

OS: debian stretch ; GRASS version: 7.2.

I'm writing a standalone python script using `grass_session`.

```
with Session(gisdb="/tmp",
             location="mylocation",
             create_opts="EPSG:4326") as sess:

    run_command('v.in.ogr',
                input='PG:host=51.51.51.51 dbname=mydb user=dbuser port=5433',
                layer='my_table',
                output='my_output',
                geometry='geom',
                where="state=\'Ok\'",
                overwrite=True
                )
    # display imported vector
    run_command('v.info', map='my_output')
```

The script works fine if the database is on the same machine (host=localhost or 127.0.0.1), but when I want to connect to a distant postgresql server it fails with

```
ERROR 1: PQconnectdb failed.
FATAL:  role "my_user" does not exist
```

`my_user` is the user running the script, not the `dbuser` that is allowed to connect to the database. I have a .pgpass file in the home of `my_user` with the password of `dbuser`.

If I try to do a connection to the db server via `psql` and the same parameters, the connection is correctly established, so the distant server accept the connection from my machine with the user dbuser and the password stored in .pgpass.

I've tried to replace `host` with `hostaddr` as it seams it's better when using IP addresses, but same result.

What am I missing?

Comment: You have a `dbuser` on the local database and a user `my_user` on the machine but on the remote database, what are your user(s)? What does `ogrinfo "PG:host=51.51.51.51 dbname=mydb user=dbuser port=5433"` return?

Comment: `dbuser` is a user (role) on the remote database

Comment: ogrinfo result is a surprise: INFO: Open of `PG:hostaddr=51.51.51.51  dbname=mydb user=dbuser port=5433'                                                                                                  
      using driver `PostgreSQL' successful.
ERROR 1: ERROR:  column s.consrc does not exist  
LINE 1: ...nrelid = c.oid AND a.attnum = ANY (s.conkey) AND (s.consrc L...   
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "s.conkey" or the column "s.conbin". 
ERROR 1: ERROR:  column s.consrc does not exist   
LINE 1: ...nrelid = c.oid AND a.attnum = ANY (s.conkey) AND (s.consrc L...

Comment: It seems to be a bug between GDAL v 2.1.2 and postgresql 12.1. When I say it works with a local database, it is on a laptop that uses GDAL v 3.0.4 and Postgresql 12.1. I have to find out how to upgrade GDAL on debian stretch. Thanks ThomasG77.